# Node js server auto restart

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am beginner in Node.js . I also made an application . I am using nodemon for auto start server. In production I want to restart my server automatically when it become down . How can I do that

```
const app = {};

app.createServer = () => {
    const server = http.createServer(app.handleReqRes);
    server.listen(environment.port, () => {
        console.log(`listening to port ${environment.port}`);
    });
}; 

app.createServer();
```

Comment: _`I want to restart my server automatically when it become down`_ When does it become down automatically?

Comment: Can u please suggest how can I make server alive all the time if it become down

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: @kashfiq read the linked question